# Having trouble printing root to leaf paths for binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, stringbuilder, depth-first-search

I am trying to print all the root to leaf paths for a binary tree and I need to return the result as a List of Strings. I am trying to use recursion and StringBuilders to do this but with each new path, instead of removing the old path, it is appending to it.

If the paths from root to leaf are 5->3->2->1, 5->3->4, 5->7->6 and 5->7->8 (the example I am using), my result is coming as the following:

5->3->2->1

5->3->2->14

5->3->2->147->6

5->3->2->147->68

This is because of the way I am using StringBuilder but I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Following is my entire code. Any help would be appreciated:

```
public class solution{
    static List<String> allPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<String> binaryTreePaths (BinaryTree bT){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        binaryTreePathsHelper(bT, sb);
        return allPaths;
    }

    public static void binaryTreePathsHelper(BinaryTree bT, StringBuilder sb){
        if (bT == null){
            return;
        }
        if (bT.getLeftChild() == null && bT.getRightChild() == null){
            sb.append(bT.getRoot() + "");
            allPaths.add(sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
        else{
            sb.append(bT.getRoot() + "->");
        }
        if (bT.getLeftChild() != null){
            binaryTreePathsHelper(bT.getLeftChild(), sb);
        }
        if (bT.getRightChild() != null){
            binaryTreePathsHelper(bT.getRightChild(), sb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a single string.  Rather, each recursive step will return a collection of paths.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when your tree has two paths from the current node.  You're passing the same instance of `StringBuilder` into both instances of `binaryTreePathsHelper`.  Which means that both paths are ending up in a single string builder.

The easiest solution is to not pass `StringBuilder` around.  Instead, pass `String` around. Then you'll be creating new `String`s each time you append to your passed-in `String`, eliminating the possibility of accidental object reuse.

If you really want to pass around instances of `StringBuilder`, you need to duplicate them when you recursively call `binaryTreePathsHelper`. For example:

```
binaryTreePathsHelper(bT.getRightChild(), new StringBuilder(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I knew I was doing that wrong because I was using the debugger in Eclipse but was blanking on how to fix it. I tried passing in copies as shallow copies but that didn't help. This fixed it perfectly so thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Let future readers know by accepting the answer as having helped you :)